# Any Hamcrest matcher to check if a collection is composed exactly of x,y elements, unregardless of order and cardinality

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

I am using hamcrest Matchers and I don't find contains, containsInAnyOrder, hasItems and containsInRelativeOrder solve that need.

I need a matcher like:

- Collection B is composed of exactly the same elements as Collection A in any order and cardinality

Its some kind of hasExactlyItems() or containsInAnyOrderAndCardinality()

Comment: So what's stopping you from writing such a matcher?

Comment: I have the feeling that there must be some matcher for this used in a certain way (such a basic need) but I can't find it

Comment: I wrote the question so fast it looks like I'm requesting a piece of code, my apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-news.html) for this purpose. It has lot of fluent assertions for the collections like:

- containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf
- containsExactlyElementsOf
- containsExactlyInAnyOrder etc.,

Comment: I would like to avoid using current framework's API but if there's no built-in matcher that can acomplish this need, I'll accept this answer